# "Couldn't load plugin" when calling knitr::include_graphics() with pdf argument in html

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

am trying to include a pdf-graphic with r-markdown. Oddly, the output with Pandoc to pdf works flawlessly. The html output writes `Couldn't load plugin` though and doesn't display anything other than that.

This is how I'm trying to call the function:

```
knitr::include_graphics("plots1.pdf")
```

Is there anything suspicious?

Comment: Same exact issue, can you please show your Pancod to pdf example?

Comment: Same problem for me, did you find a solution? Cheers!

Comment: I think this issue is only related to the RStudio markdown viewer. Opening the markdown document in a web browser has worked for me in some cases.